# Can’t make |completed| of reminder id "x-apple-reminder://..." into type specifier

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to check if a reminder is complete on OS X 10.11.5 and if it is not then to display a dialog. Here's my code:

```
tell application "Reminders" to set rems to reminders in default list
repeat with rem in rems
    if completed of rem is false then display dialog "A reminder is incomplete."
end repeat
```

However I always get this error:

```
Can’t make |completed| of reminder id \"x-apple-reminder://E3FCE788-80E7-432C-845C-F3CF1A7CD6B1\" into type specifier."
```

I don't know why. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**completed** is a term of the "**Reminders**" application, so you must put the code in the `tell application` block, like this:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set rems to reminders in default list
    repeat with rem in rems
        if completed of rem is false then display dialog "A reminder is incomplete."
    end repeat
end tell
```